# Failed to Start Apache Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssl-certificate

I tried to configure my WebPage SSL Certificate, after configured it I restarted Apache Service and the output is the next:

```
 httpd24-httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd24-httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-11-27 12:32:27 EST; 23s ago
  Process: 22104 ExecStop=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper $OPTIONS -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 22102 ExecStart=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22102 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com httpd-scl-wrapper[22102]: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper: line 7: /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment: No such file or directory
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com httpd-scl-wrapper[22104]: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper: line 7: /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment: No such file or directory
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd24-httpd.service entered failed state.
Nov 27 12:32:27 swlt.pok.ibm.com systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service failed.
```

My SSL files are generated, as much as **key**, **crt** and **pem**.

I have checked the line:

```
 /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper: line 7: /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment: No such file or directory
```

This is my file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment         ##Line 7
for sclname in $HTTPD24_HTTPD_SCLS_ENABLED ; do
    . /opt/rh/$sclname/enable
    export X_SCLS="$X_SCLS $sclname"
done

exec /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd "$@"
```

I want to know what is falling in this case.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear: The file `/opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment` that should be [sourced](https://superuser.com/a/46146) in `##Line 7` does not exist (or maybe is just not readable due to some SELinux issues).

Comment: Into path only I have the certs (certificates) folder and root folder. Before modify ssl.conf with certificates, I had the paths of .key, .pem and crt files. And it was working.